# Getting extra rufus-scheduler thread with each delayed_job rake jobs:work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rufus-scheduler

Am trying to use rufus-scheduler to check every minute or so to see if
there are jobs ready to be placed in the delayed_job queue.

Have an initializer script in #{RAILS_ROOT}/config/initializers that
starts the scheduler.   Unfortunately the rake jobs:work also runs the
rails initialization process so another gets started for each
jobs:work started.

How can I prevent this?

Running ruby 1.8.6.26, rails 2.3.5, dj 1.8.5, rufus-scheduler 2.0.6 on
XP pro sp3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your initializer, find a way not to run the schedule if the rails initialization process is invoked via Rake.

For sure there is a more railsy way, but you could do

```
  unless defined?(Rake)
    # do the scheduling...
  end
```

The block 'do the scheduling' won't get called if the constant Rake is defined (for a Rake task it is defined).

Comment: Looks like a good idea.  Am trying it out and will report results here.
Thanks!!

Comment: Works a charm!
Thanks, again!