# Heroku Delayed_Job firing twice when run through rufus_scheduler

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, delayed-job, rufus-scheduler

I realize this title is a mouthful...

My app is currently setup to send out emails to all users each day when there has been activity on the account. To achieve this, **I run a cron task through rufus_scheduler, and delay the email delivery using delayed_job** which looks something like this:

```
scheduler.cron("0 12 * * *") do
  User.all.each do |user|
    Newideas.delay.newideas_email(user)
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, it seems that using this combination (**rufus_scheduler & delayed_job**) is causing the emails to be delivered twice to each user when deployed on Heroku.

I've tried to replicate this in development, but I've been unable to. Also, the problem doesn't occur when I trigger a delayed_job using a controller method - i.e. when someone creates a new account, etc.

Any help in sorting this out would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use the Heroku scheduler and call it via that? It spawns a seperate process so then there's no need to use delayed_job in there as well...simplify :)

Comment: I was using delayed job inside the scheduler because some of the tasks take a long time to perform, so without delayed_job they were timing out. Also, I would've used the Heroku scheduler, but when we first built the app, only Cron was available, which didn't run frequently enough for us to use it.  I'm now switching everything over to Heroku Scheduler though to see if that resolves the problem - for reference this is also what Heroku Support recommended that I do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the reason for this is simply, that you call `scheduler.cron` in a `config/initializer/what_ever`
file and so the scheduler is running in the rails process **AND** and in the delayed_job process?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661608/getting-extra-rufus-scheduler-thread-with-each-delayed-job-rake-jobswork) may be a simple answer to that question.